# Rails API Versioning, Routing issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, routes, versioning

I'm trying to implement a simple rails api app with versioning, based on [Railscasts #350 episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/350-rest-api-versioning?view=asciicast). I wanted to access a specific API version of the app by providing the version through **`Accept header`** in this format: `application/vnd.rails5_api_test.v1`. And when no `Accept header` is provided the request will be routed to the current default version of the app. To handle this I have created an `api_constraints` file in my `lib directory` which is to be required in routes.

I have created two versions of the app `v1` and `v2` in which, `v1` has the `Users resource` and `v2` has `Users and Comments resources`. 
Everything was working as expected, except for when I request URL `localhost:3000/comments` by passing version `1` through the headers using Postman, I'm getting the response from the `comments resource`, displaying all the comments. But I'm expecting the response to be `status: 404 Not Found`, as the `comments resource` was in version `2` and the requested version is `1`.

This is the response from the server:

```
Started GET "/comments" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-04-01 20:57:53 +0530
Processing by Api::V2::CommentsController#index as application/vnd.rails5_api_test.v1
  Comment Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments"
[active_model_serializers]   User Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
[active_model_serializers] Rendered ActiveModel::Serializer::CollectionSerializer with ActiveModelSerializers::Adapter::JsonApi (4.32ms)
Completed 200 OK in 7ms (Views: 5.0ms | ActiveRecord: 1.5ms)
```

Here are my working files:
Constraints file, **lib/api_constraints.rb**:

```
class APIConstraints
  def initialize(options)
    @version = options[:version]
    @default = options[:default]
  end

  def matches?(req)
    req.headers["Accept"].include?(media_type) || @default
  end

  private

  def media_type
    "application/vnd.rails5_api_test.v#{@version}"
  end
end
```

Routes file, **config/routes.rb**:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  require "api_constraints"

  scope module: 'api/v1', constraints: APIConstraints.new(version: 1) do
    resources :users
  end

  scope module: 'api/v2', constraints: APIConstraints.new(version: 2, default: true) do
    resources :users
    resources :comments
  end
end
```

Users controller for v1, **api/v1/users_controller.rb**:

```
class Api::V1::UsersController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @users = User.all

    render json: @users, each_serializer: ::V1::UserSerializer
  end
end
```

Users controller for v2, **api/v2/users_controller.rb**:

```
class Api::V2::UsersController < Api::V1::UsersController

  def index
    @users = User.all

    render json: @users, each_serializer: ::V2::UserSerializer
  end

end
```

Comments controller for v2, **api/v2/comments_controller.rb**:

```
class Api::V2::CommentsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @comments = Comment.all

    render json: @comments, each_serializer: ::V2::CommentSerializer
  end
end
```

user serializer for v1, **user_serializer.rb**:

```
class V1::UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :email
end
```

user serializer for v2, **user_serializer.rb**:

```
class V2::UserSerializer < V1::UserSerializer

  has_many :comments
end
```

comments serializer for v2, **comment_serializer.rb**:

```
class V2::CommentSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :description

  belongs_to :user
end
```

I have tried removing the `default: true` option in the routes and then it is working as expected. But I want it to work with default option.

Could anyone please let me know where I'm getting this wrong and also share your thoughts on this approach. If this one is not the best way to do, then guide me through the correct way of implementing it. Thanks in advance for anyone who takes time in helping me out. :) Cheers!

Comment: Can i see your `comments_controller.rb` too

Comment: oops! I've missed that file. Updated the post with `comments_controller.rb`. Check and let me know if you have any thoughts. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this can be solved easily as the v1 doesn't have comments the v2 will be matched regardless.

Is you APIConstraints using this method?

```
  def matches?(req)
    @default || req.headers['Accept'].include?("application/vnd.example.v#{@version}")
  end
```

I think the method is a bit too loose here and should look like this to ignore requests that do have a version.

```
  def matches?(req)
    (@default &&
         req.headers['Accept'].grep(/^application/vnd.example.v\d+/$).empty?
    ) || req.headers['Accept'].include?("application/vnd.example.v#{@version}")
  end
```

Comment: Thanks for your time Thomas. I think you're right. I'll write my method like you've mentioned and will let you know.

Comment: using grep was returning `NoMethodError`. However, I've tried in the way you pointed me., using the match method it is actually working :) here's what I've tried:          `req.headers['Accept'].match(/^application\/vnd\.example\.v\d/).blank?)`.  
The `empty?` on MatchData returns `NoMethodError` and if MatchData is nil, `empty?` returns the same error, as `empty?` method doesn't work on nil. So, I've used the Rails `blank?` method. Now it is working as expected! Thanks for helping me out to get this working :) cheers!

Comment: There are so many ways :) Maybe `grep` is just a very new function.
`req.headers['Accept'].any?{|s| s.match(/^application\/vnd\.example\.v\d/) }`.

Don't forget to accept my answer.